# PHP - Google App Engine app.yaml "has custom peformance settings"

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload this as my app.yaml

```
application: *******
version: 2
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: 5
  min_pending_latency: 5.0s
  max_pending_latency: 7.7s

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /resources
  static_dir: resources
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /test.php
  script: test.php
- url: .*
  script: home/service/index.php
```

How ever every time I do upload it, it says I am using custom peformance settings and to look at the application section. This is the exact error I get **Your application currently has custom performance settings that are not compatible with the Modules feature. You must either clear or migrate these application-level settings before you can upload a non-default module. See the Performance section of the Application Settings page of the Admin Console for more information.**

So I looked at the migrate to app section and here is what it says.

```
application: ********
# Other settings here...
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: 5
  min_pending_latency: 5.0s
  max_pending_latency: 7.7s
```

I've followed the guides as close as possible, I am not sure what is wrong with my app.yaml? I have removed all the other .yaml files (I had a pdf.yaml [module] and a dispatch.yaml) it all booted up fine on the local dev machine but when I call appcfg.py update app.yaml - I just get told of my issue with custom performance settings, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's funny every time I post to Stackoverflow, I always find a solution soon after (I've been trying to solve this issue for days btw)

You have to set all the application settings to Automatic on the Old-Settings page, and suddenly modules work.

Cheers